# How can I create a field of numbers that repeats the times of itself?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I got a geometry node (GN) related problem here.

The project that I'm working on requires a field input of random numbers that have to repeat the same time of itself. They will be used as selection input. 
For example, like 223331555554444... or 33322122666666....

I can not figure out an easy way, but I am  somehow close already. There is just a tiny little issue at the end.

[image]

As you can see in this GIF image, I basically use compare nodes to select the range of where each number should be and then times it to the number itself (since the selected range will output value of 1).

In this GIF image I first browse through the integer 01234 and the viewer can output the right field number for each input, but as soon as I plug in the index input, it only works for the first number in the field. I guess the problem my caused by the Boolean range since it doesn’t work this way.

So what should I do to output a whole list of this field?

Or is there a better way to make this number list?

---

I think [quellenform has the solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269004/how-to-create-a-field-of-numbers-that-repeat-the-times-of-itself/269010#269010) to solve my ultimate problem. But I’m still curious about how to make my method work, because it's so close and logically ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no node that will do such repetitions for you, so you would have to resort to a trick.

One possibility is this one:

[image]

Here I instantiate a simple geometry (which I only use temporarily, and which is not ultimately output as geometry) at the existing points in the form of curves.

The trick here is that curves can be subdivided arbitrarily without losing the *Spline Index*.

So you can create random values with which to subdivide the individual curves. Each subdivision inserts further indexes to the list of points, which then gives you the desired repetition.

The only catch in general is that the node `Random Value` generates relatively often repetitions of a value at low ranges...

Comment: Alright senpai!! It is the second time you guided me through the mist in a week! It is indeed a very tricky apporach. It solves my problem for sure. This is actually a followed up problem of last question you helped with. You should have a share if this project makes money lol! Thank you for your help! Hope to see you around next time! Wish you the best!

Comment: Clean! I don't get the low-range-bias thing...

Comment: @RobinBetts By this I meant that the so called "Random Values", for example in the range 1 - 6, are often found in succession, So for example the resulting sequence of numbers 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 6, 6, 6, 5, 3, etc. Here are two twos and three sixes in a row. But this is what `Random Value` generates. The larger the range, the less likely the repetitions in a row.

Comment: @RobinBetts Uh, no, I obviously didn't express myself clearly: The numbers are generated randomly (numbers within the defined range), but relatively often numbers of the same value follow each other. Of course, this happens more often the smaller the range is. And there is no additional option in the node to avoid this behaviour.

Comment: Ahh... OK. For the distribution to be **non**-random in a way that might suit the OP, you'd need some sort of 'not the same as last time, please'.

Comment: @RobinBetts ...exactly!